# What is the importance of frames per second in JSlider and what values to choose?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am learning how to use the `JSlider` from [oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html). I want to use it to change the value of a variable in my code and not to change the speed/fps of animations. I notice this "frames per second" which I see in computer games and read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate). I saw different JSlider examples and they all use different values for the FPS constants. How do I decide which values to use for the JSlider FPS constants ? Also, why do we make them constants and not variables ?  Should I  just copy paste these values into all my code that uses JSlider ?

```
static final int FPS_MIN = 0;
static final int FPS_MAX = 30;
static final int FPS_INIT = 15;    //initial frames per second
. . .
JSlider framesPerSecond = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,
                                  FPS_MIN, FPS_MAX, FPS_INIT);
framesPerSecond.addChangeListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I decide which values to use for the JSlider FPS constants ?

It depends on your requirements. Too slow and the animation looks bad. Too fast and the computer can't keep up. Also monitors only refresh at a given frequency anyway. I think I saw in another posting 60 would be a good max.

> Should I just copy paste these values into all my code that uses JSlider ?

Sliders can be used to something other than a FPS function. So the values you choose depend on your requirements.

Comment: the values you choose depend on your requirements - If I am using it to turn on the volume of a speaker, then what could the values be ?

Comment: Do the FPS numbers always have to be constants ?

Comment: What values does your speaker API accept? Unless you have an API that would allow you to change the ranges you would probably make them Constants. Isn't that the difference between a Constant and a Variable?